# Upper bound on the number of vertex transitive graphs

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Is there a known upper bound on the number of vertex transitive graphs on $n$ vertices?

Comment: $2^{n-1}$ times the number of minimal transitive groups would be a fair bound, but I don't know a bound on the number of minimal transitive groups.  For this reason, adding a group category to your question might be a good idea.

Comment: What is the reason for the $2^{n-1}$ factor?

Comment: There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to choose the neighbours of the first vertex.  Then the group action gives all the other edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think only very rough bounds are known.
In http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5736, it is conjectured that the answer for fixed valency d is roughly of the form $n^{d\log n}$. 
This is proved for Cayley graphs and for $d=3$.

As Brendan mentions, obtaining upper bounds on the number of minimal transitive groups of a given degree would yield upper bounds. The best results in this direction are due to Pyber, I believe, but are not tight. I think this may be in :

Pyber, László
Asymptotic results for permutation groups. (English summary) Groups and computation (New Brunswick, NJ, 1991), 197–219, 
DIMACS Ser. Discrete Math. Theoret. Comput. Sci., 11, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1993.